# MIPS/UP16 Branch instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

I have my school project and on the paper it wrote

```
1 nop
2 add $1, $2;    //RF[1]=RF[1]=RF[2]
3 beq $1, $3, #1 //if (RF[1]==RF[3]) skip inst 5
4 nop
5 add $4, $1     //RF[4]=RF[4]+RF[1]
6 add $5, $1     //RF[5]=RF[5]+RF[1]
```

So at line 3, BEQ in the instruction SET is

```
pc += sign_ext(immed) + 1;
```

So wouldnt, the PC be at (3+1+1) = 5 instead of skipping instruction 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a suspicious `nop` after the `beq`, so you should look in the manual whether MIPS has *delayed branches*, which means that before branching, the next instruction will always be executed. And this instruction might then count towards the `pc`.

(Just guessing, since I don't know MIPS, but [Wikipedia does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot).)

Comment: The Wikipedia article is interesting.  I like this line in the article...   " and the more recently designed Alpha "